# Wildcard in nodejs sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

How can I use wildcards with a parameter in the nodejs version of sqlite3? Code:

```
let db = new sqlite.Database(...)
const param = 'x'
db.all('select * from mytable where name like "%?%"', [param], (err, rows) => {
    ...
```

This results in

> SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range

Some suggests adding the wilcards into the query string like this:

```
const param = '%' + 'x' + '%'
```

But that seems to result in literally searching for name like "%x%", instead of using wildcards. I know the query I'm trying to run is correct because it returns the expected rows in the sqlite3 cli. How can I achieve the same thing in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include %% in the parameter and drop the double quotation marks:

```
const search = 'x';
const param = '%' + search + '%';
db.all('select * from mytable where name like ?', [param], (err, rows) => {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards within parameters:

```
let db = new sqlite.Database(...)
const param = {$name: '%Alice%'}
db.all('select * from mytable where name like $name', param, (err, rows) => {
```